# I get the error while importing the fastai library after install

Tags: python, python-3.x, fast-ai

I would like to use the fastai library to perform text processing. First job I installed the fastai library. I used to import it later, but without any code, it only gives an import error.

I am using Python 3.5.2

My OS Ubuntu 16.04

asd.py

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.text import *
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ali/Desktop/asd.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fastai.text import *
  File "/home/ali/Desktop/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastai/text.py", line 8
    re_tok = re.compile(f'([{string.punctuation}“”¨«»®´·º½¾¿¡§£₤‘’])')
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just downloading and importing the library may be caused by this error.

Comment: Solution: (F '([{the} string.punctuatio "" ¨ «» £ ₤ ®'· º½¾¿¡§' '])) after the string-shaped identification feature from python3.6 version. Therefore, installing python version 3.6 and above resolves the problem.